# Assistance needed in sorting Python output of a ping sweep

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort the output of a python command for a ping sweep and I'm seeing some odd results.  I borrowed the following from another post, which returns a liat of IP addresses that are not sorted:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os

def pinger( job_q, results_q ):
DEVNULL = open(os.devnull,'w')
while True:
    ip = job_q.get()
    if ip is None: break

    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['ping','-c1',ip],
                              stdout=DEVNULL)
        results_q.put(ip)
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_size = 55

jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
results = multiprocessing.Queue()

pool = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=pinger, args=(jobs,results))
         for i in range(pool_size) ]

for p in pool:
    p.start()

for i in range(200,254):
    jobs.put('192.168.1.{0}'.format(i))

for p in pool:
    jobs.put(None)

for p in pool:
    p.join()

while not results.empty():
    ip = results.get()
print(ip)
```

And then I modified this command: 
from: **results_q.put(ip)**
to: **results_q.put(sorted(ip))**

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os

def pinger( job_q, results_q ):
DEVNULL = open(os.devnull,'w')
while True:
    ip = job_q.get()
    if ip is None: break

    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['ping','-c1',ip],
                              stdout=DEVNULL)
        results_q.put(sorted(ip))
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
pool_size = 55

jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
results = multiprocessing.Queue()

pool = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=pinger, args=(jobs,results))
         for i in range(pool_size) ]

for p in pool:
    p.start()

for i in range(200,254):
    jobs.put('192.168.1.{0}'.format(i))

for p in pool:
    jobs.put(None)

for p in pool:
    p.join()

while not results.empty():
    ip = results.get()
print(ip)
```

I was expecting a sorted list but instead I am seeing the following:

```
# ./pingloop.py
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6', '8', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '4', '4', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '5', '6', '8', '9']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '5', '6', '8', '9']
```

Thoughts on what to change in order to sort the returned list of live IP addresses, rather than parsing through each address and breaking down the characters contained within each?

Comment: strings are iterables too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the final section of code to:

```
ips = []
while not results.empty():
    ips.append(results.get())
ips.sort()
for ip in ips:
    print(ip)
```

This collects the ip addresses in a list, sorts the list in place and then prints the sorted ip addresses.

Comment: That gave me the same results as before - each character.

Comment: @CMB I amended my answer, hope it works for you now.